# Making a web app native (kind of...)

Tags: php, web-applications, mobile

I have already spent a lot of time on Google, but have not found what I am looking for.

I have a PHP based web app that uses jquery mobile. I want to get it to the apple & android app store so people can find it and use it like an app. All I really need is something that acts as a container (i.e. web browser) to go to our site. The app needs data from our servers, so it only works when they are online. Since it is PHP, I can't do any converting. PhoneGap seems more complicated than we need.

Is there a simple\free solution out there? Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: if you could make the web app, is it that hard to follow a tutorial on web views?

Comment: No; it's not about being too hard. The point is that we don't need that kind of functionality. The app is php based (all server side stuff). We don't need to any native functionality. We just want to offer the convenience of accessing our service like a native app.

Comment: my point is, creating a web-view based app yourself is easy enough that it won't take longer than searching and getting started with any solution you may find, so just do it yourself

Comment: I wouldn't have asked here without spending a bit of time on google first. I was just hoping for a few suggestions of other services (like phoneGap). I don't care about difficulty level. The problem is that the services I found so far are not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it yourself using the Android WebView and Apple UIWebView.  Since you have the webapp in PHP on the Internets somewhere, just format that to fit mobile screens properly, then create the applications to utilize the WebViews.

Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

iPhone: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Follow a couple tutorials on each and you could have something up and running very quickly.

Edit: This link has a sample application (for android) associated with the tutorial for download: [http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.htm](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html)

And I think there are a couple decent UIWebView (Apple) tutorials on YouTube.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of answer I was looking for. I'll check into those links. The web app is already designed for mobile devices (ala jQuery mobile) so I don't need to update the site.

Comment: @BrNathanH Excluding the time it takes to get the environments set up (which with d/ling the SDK and all can add up) actually getting an app running on your phone displaying a website (using webviews) in app form will literally take under 30 mins.  Clearly it will increase when you start messing around with native elements and such, but getting it up and running is minor.

Comment: I'm not a mac person and have not had much contact with Java, but it sounds easy enough. Thanks.